# Update for Windows Defender - KB2267602

Tags: windows-8

I am running Win 8, updated to 8.1. Is it a concern that definition update for Windows Defender,KB2267602, cannot be uninstalled?

I have visited forums that advise to never install an update that cannot be "uninstalled"?

Comment: Short answer: You're fine.

Answer (score 0):

The update in question adds data to the database for Windows Defender. It helps the program recongize [malware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware) that it probably wouldn't be able to find without the update.